# Slots in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Are there any approaches to separating basic components that can have different content. For example, like slots in Vue?

Let's take the example of a modal window for edit/create forms.

I want to have a basic modal view with scripts/styles/css through the whole application, in which I am going to nest add/edit views components/partitial_views for different models and situatioins

Like this:

```
<MyModal class = "...">  // modal template
    <slot/>  //  <-- it can be EditorTemplates here... or just a views... 
</MyModal>
<scripts>...</scripts>
<styles>...</styles>
```

Any thoughts would be helpful to me.

I just want to have app-wide templates on top of the edit and create forms

Comment: In short, this is not an out-of-the-box feature of MVC. It can be done, but I can't find any existing implementation that matches VueJs slots.

Answer (score -1):

There is a concept called View Components in ASP.NET Core. It is similar to the partial view but they are more powerful than the partial view.

You can create view components for each on and put that in the your application.

You can find more about that here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Another best thing you can do is use vue.js in your views and that way you will get best of both world